# How to align the labels on a circular axis with amCharts 4?

Tags: javascript, svg, amcharts4

Consider a radial bar chart:

[image]

Not easy for me to describe my problem in English... I hope I will be clear enough. As you can see, the country names are radially aligned along the inner radius: you can imagine a circle which fits the interior area delimited by the country names. I would like the country names to be radially aligned along the *outer* radius. That is, the "U" of UK, the "F" of France, the "A" of USA, the "a" of China, the "n" of Japan and the "G" of Germany "aligned" on a circle.

I built this chart with a code similar to the one of [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/radial-histogram/), and [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stla/fk7dn1zh/) if this can help.

I tried to change the properties `textAlign`, `align`, `horizontalCenter`, etc, but this had no effect.